# Convert multiple bit columns into one field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table that contains multiple bit columns, and what I'm wanting to do is convert it for display purposes with a hard-coded label based on the bit column values. This is shown in the highlighted yellow column name expectedresult.

[image]

Test Data

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testbit](
    [StaffId] [int] NULL,
    [type1] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [type2] [bit] NULL,
    [type3] [bit] NULL,
    [type4] [bit] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[testbit] ([StaffId], [type1], [type2], [type3], [type4]) VALUES (1, 1, 0, 0, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[testbit] ([StaffId], [type1], [type2], [type3], [type4]) VALUES (2, 0, 1, 0, 0)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[testbit] ([StaffId], [type1], [type2], [type3], [type4]) VALUES (3, 1, 1, 1, 1)
GO
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `CASE WHEN <expr>` or `CASE <expr> WHEN <value>` expression, then concatenate in an outer-query with `CONCAT_WS`.

- A `CASE` expression evaluates to `NULL` when an `ELSE` case is omitted, so these expressions are equivalent:

  ```
  CASE x WHEN 1 THEN 'foo' END
  CASE x WHEN 1 THEN 'foo' ELSE NULL END
  CASE WHEN x = 1 THEN 'foo' END
  CASE WHEN x = 1 THEN 'foo' ELSE NULL END
  ```
- [The `CONCAT_WS` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is variadic and concatenates non-NULL strings with the separator string (the first argument).

  ```
  CONCAT_WS( ', ', 'a', 'b', NULL, NULL, 'c' ) == 'a, b, c'
  ```

Here's how I'd do it:

```
SELECT
    StaffId,
    CONCAT_WS( ', ', Type1Text, Type2Text, Type3Text, Type4Text ) AS TypeNames
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            StaffId,
            CASE type1 WHEN 1 THEN 'Type1Name' END AS Type1Text,
            CASE type2 WHEN 1 THEN 'Type2Name' END AS Type2Text,
            CASE type2 WHEN 1 THEN 'Type3Name' END AS Type3Text,
            CASE type3 WHEN 1 THEN 'Type4Name' END AS Type4Text
        FROM
            ...
    ) AS iq
```

The outer query can be elided if you don't mind making it slightly harder to read:

```
SELECT
    StaffId,
    CONCAT_WS( ', ',
        CASE type1 WHEN 1 THEN 'Type1Name' END AS Type1Text,
        CASE type2 WHEN 1 THEN 'Type2Name' END AS Type2Text,
        CASE type2 WHEN 1 THEN 'Type3Name' END AS Type3Text,
        CASE type3 WHEN 1 THEN 'Type4Name' END AS Type4Text
    ) AS TypeNames
FROM
    ...
```